# Laravel 5.2 and button links

Tags: laravel-5

i have to make button link EDIT in Laravel 5.2. This one is made in earliest versions laravel and doesn't work in 5.2.

{{ link_to_route('task.edit' , 'Edit' , **[$task->id]** , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'] }}

Is there any idea for that? I have no idea what should i do with  **$task->id**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('task.edit', ['id' => $task->id]) }}">
  Edit
</a>
```